# Tabs to span multiple rows

Tags: java, android

can anyone point me in the right direction for making an android layout that has multiple rows of tabs? i have about 15 tabs that are unreadable when the app opens.

Answer (score 1):

Well, sometime ago I ended in the same problem. My conclusions:

- AFAIK you cannot (correct me, if I wrong) create two/three layered tabs using TabHost/TabWidget.
- You can create tabs in a `HorizontalScrollView`. This way, there will be 1 row of the tabs, but they will be horizontal scrollable.
- You can create `TabHost`, but make your own `TabWidget` using buttons with selectors (which may look exactly the same like the system tabs), placed in e.g. `FrameLayout`. Then you can use `TabHost.setCurrentTab()` method to achive tab-like behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do something similar with tabs in different rows and couldn't find an easy way to do it with TabHosts, so I ended up using [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html).

You can use the FragmentActivity to lay out your tabs (or buttons) however you want and then use Fragments to switch out the main view with a FragmentManager in the tab's OnClickHandler.